# E500 Internal Server Error When Installing Package in Atom

Tags: npm, atom-editor

I'm currently trying to install the package atom-beautify to my Atom IDE. When attempting to do so I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code E500
> npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error - GET https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-beautify/versions/0.33.4/tarball

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\User.atom.apm_logs\2022-04-19T03_03_14_465Z-debug.log

I understand that this may be solved with downloading additional command-line tools as I currently only have the Windows default tools and Git.
If anybody could give me any information on how to fix this issue that would be great.

Thanks :)

Comment: same for me today with different plugins, may some server side problem

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an issue with the Atom servers. Issue opened on Atom github portal.

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/25417

Answer (score 0):

Issue is from yesterday I think, I try to reinstall Atom several times and change the configuration but the issue persist, I search more information into Atom official blogs and didn't find like the root cause or anything related
Maybe server are down because is not related with the atom basic configuration or apm
Hope to solve soon.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Atom servers. any package i tried to install these days fails.

**An alternative** to install **atom-beautify** is using its **github** repo.

So use

`apm install Glavin001/atom-beautify`

references to my answer

https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/355#issuecomment-116411783
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/25417#issuecomment-1103834423

Use this to install any atom package available on github